# Is it possible that AutocompleteInput can be resettable?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

AutocompleteInput is pretty good to use in react admin. However, is there a way to make it resettable? Thanks!

```
<ReferenceInput
    label={translate('resources.cards.fields.search_name')}
    source="id"
    reference="cards"
    alwaysOn
    resettable
>
    <AutocompleteInput optionText="name" inputValueMatcher={() => null} resettable />
</ReferenceInput>
```

I put resettable for both ReferenceInput and also AutocompleteInput but the reset button just doesn't show up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, it looks like it is not possible at this moment:

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2564

**UPDATE:** It is possible now! :)